# Why is creating a new array instead of emptying the old one causing a problem here?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mithril.js

I'm working on a project in Javascript and hit a problem that I don't understand.
Basically I've written a map generator that is generating maps from noise, that bit is fine and working.
I want the end user to be able to edit this map by placing what I call actions (basically shapes which effect the underlying noise generation) and the system for editing these is causing problems.

I'm using [Mithril JS](https://mithril.js.org/) to update a UI to edit properties of the actions and it's mostly working. Part of what I need to be able to do is to click on an action and select it, this will show it in the UI to allow you to edit it. Selecting an action works, as does deselecting or selecting another action, but if I then delete an action it no longer shows in the UI. Here's the relevant snippet of code:

```
var editModeElements = {
    actions: editedActions.actions,
    selectedAction: [],
    selectedPoint: null,
    update: function() {
        this.actions = editedActions;
        this.clearSelection();
        m.redraw();
    },
    deleteAction: function(action) {
        for( var i = 0; i < this.actions.actions.length; i++)
        { 
            if ( this.actions.actions[i] == action) 
            { 
                this.actions.actions.splice(i, 1); i--; 
            }
        }
        this.clearSelection();
        unsavedEdits = true;
    },
    selectAction: function(action) {
        this.selectedAction = new Array();
        this.selectedPoint = null;
        this.selectedAction.push(action);
        m.redraw();
        viewport.redraw();
    },
    clearSelection: function() {
        this.selectedAction = new Array();
        this.selectedPoint = null;
        m.redraw();
        viewport.redraw();
    },
    addAction: function(actionType) {
        var action = createBlankAction(actionType);
        this.actions.actions.push(action);
        this.selectAction(action);
        unsavedEdits = true;
    },
    oncreate: this.update,
    view: function() {
        return m(".action-dialog", [
                m(".action-editor-buttons", [
                    m(".new-action", {onclick: function() {editModeElements.addAction(MASK_TYPE.CIRCLE)}}, "Circle"),
                    m(".new-action", {onclick: function() {editModeElements.addAction(MASK_TYPE.RECTANGLE)}}, "Rectangle"),
                    m(".new-action", {onclick: function() {editModeElements.addAction(MASK_TYPE.POLYGON)}}, "Polygon"),
                    m(".new-action", {onclick: function() {editModeElements.addAction(MASK_TYPE.LINE)}}, "Line"),
                    m(".new-action", {onclick: function() {editModeElements.addAction(MASK_TYPE.COMPLEX_CIRCLE)}}, "Complex Circle"),
                    m(".new-action", {onclick: function() {editModeElements.addAction(MASK_TYPE.COMPLEX_RECTANGLE)}}, "Complex Rectangle"),
                    m(".new-action", {onclick: function() {editModeElements.addAction(MASK_TYPE.COMPLEX_POLYGON)}}, "Complex Polygon"),
                    m(".new-action", {onclick: function() {editModeElements.addAction(MASK_TYPE.COMPLEX_LINE)}}, "Complex Line"),
                ]),
                createActionEditorList(this.selectedAction, this),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Hopefully that's enough to tell me where I'm going wrong. The issue is something to do with creating a new array when I call `clearSelection`. If I remove that call from `deleteSelection` the problem goes away (but the deleted element remains selected in the UI, which is undesirable) or if I change the part in `clearSelection` to pop the element instead of creating a new array it works.

However, and this is what confuses me, `clearSelection` works fine (new array or pop method) when I use it to deselect by clicking outside an action and I also create a new Array in `selectAction` which causes no issues. It only stops working once `deleteSelection` is called.
The array that the element is deleted from in `deleteSelection` isn't particularly connected to the `selectedAction` array other than the action which is selected comes from it so I can't see it would cause these issues. I also changed it from filter (which would create a new array) to splice (which doesn't) to see if that helped, but no change.
The actions still select after a delete and change colour, they can also be dragged around successfully and saved so the issue is obviously the connection to the UI.

I don't think anything else outside this snippet is relevant as it's largely self contained, the function `createActionEditorList` at the end just turns the actions into HTML elements for the UI, works and is quite long so I haven't included it.

Why does creating a new Array break my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mithril.js now recommends that you use closures for stateful components.  I would recommend migrating to that style because it is a lot easier to reason about where the state is.

[Mithril documentation outlining closure components](https://mithril.js.org/components.html#closure-component-state):

> In the above examples, each component is defined as a POJO (Plain Old
> JavaScript Object), which is used by Mithril internally as the
> prototype for that component's instances. It's possible to use
> component state with a POJO (as we'll discuss below), but it's not the
> cleanest or simplest approach.

Regarding the bug you are having, after some testing I think it has to do with the fact that the `this` you are using in your methods is not the same as `editModeElements`.  As I understand it, mithril uses the POJO as the protoype for the `this` used in methods.  I think maybe when cutting your code down some parts have been altered that make the error occur slightly different for me when I try to make it run.  The crux of the issue though is that `this` != `editModeElements` and it makes the code really confusing.  Sometimes you might be modifying the prototype and other times you might be modifying the instance.

Some of the issues:

1. When you set `oncreate: this.update`, the `this` is not `editModeElements` but the this of the current scope.  So most likely `this.update` is undefined and oncreate is set to undefined and never called.
2. The `this` passed to `createActionEditorList` is not the same object as `editModeElements.addAction` used in `editModeElements.addAction`.
3. You have some methods refer to `actions.actions` but `editModeElements` is initialized such that `actions: editedActions.actions`.

It is hard to tell what else is going on without the rest of your code.  I tried to use POJOs for state at first because I thought that was necessary but closures are way easier to understand.  Maybe you could elaborate if you need that style for some reason because it is very difficult to implement reliably.

Here is what I think you want your component to do rewritten using the closure style, I had to stub a few things to make it work, :

```
// STUB
var MASK_TYPE = {
  CIRCLE: "CIRCLE",
  RECTANGLE: "RECTANGLE",
  POLYGON: "POLYGON",
  LINE: "LINE",
  COMPLEX_CIRCLE: "COMPLEX_CIRCLE",
  COMPLEX_RECTANGLE: "COMPLEX_RECTANGLE",
  COMPLEX_POLYGON: "COMPLEX_POLYGON",
  COMPLEX_LINE: "COMPLEX_LINE",
};

function createBlankAction(actionMask) {
  // STUB
  return {mask: actionMask};
}

var EditModeElements = function () {
  var actions = [],
      selectedAction = [],
      selectedPoint = null,
      unsavedEdits = false;
  function deleteAction(action) {
      for( var i = 0; i < actions.length; i++) { 
          if (actions[i] == action)  { 
              actions.splice(i, 1); i--; 
          }
      }
      clearSelection();
      unsavedEdits = true;
  }
  function selectAction(action) {
      selectedAction.length = 0;
      selectedPoint = null;
      selectedAction.push(action);
      //?viewport.redraw();
  }
  function clearSelection() {
      selectedAction.length = 0;
      selectedPoint = null;
      //?viewport.redraw();
  }
  function addAction(actionType) {
    var action = createBlankAction(actionType);
    actions.push(action);
    selectAction(action);
    unsavedEdits = true;
  }      
  return {
    view: function() {
        return m(".action-dialog", [
                m(".action-editor-buttons", [
                    m(".new-action", {onclick: function() {addAction(MASK_TYPE.CIRCLE)}}, "Circle"),
                    m(".new-action", {onclick: function() {addAction(MASK_TYPE.RECTANGLE)}}, "Rectangle"),
                    m(".new-action", {onclick: function() {addAction(MASK_TYPE.POLYGON)}}, "Polygon"),
                    m(".new-action", {onclick: function() {addAction(MASK_TYPE.LINE)}}, "Line"),
                    m(".new-action", {onclick: function() {addAction(MASK_TYPE.COMPLEX_CIRCLE)}}, "Complex Circle"),
                    m(".new-action", {onclick: function() {addAction(MASK_TYPE.COMPLEX_RECTANGLE)}}, "Complex Rectangle"),
                    m(".new-action", {onclick: function() {addAction(MASK_TYPE.COMPLEX_POLYGON)}}, "Complex Polygon"),
                    m(".new-action", {onclick: function() {addAction(MASK_TYPE.COMPLEX_LINE)}}, "Complex Line"),
                ]),
                m(ActionEditorList, {actions: actions, onDeleteAction: deleteAction}),
        ]);
    }
  };
}

function ActionEditorList() {
  return {
    view: function (vnode) {
      return m('', vnode.attrs.actions.map(function (a) {
        return m('b', {
          onclick: function () { 
            vnode.attrs.onDeleteAction(a);
          }
        }, a.mask);
      }));
    }
  }
}

m.mount(document.body, EditModeElements);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did wonder if the problem was scopes and my use of this but couldn't find any errors or discrepancies. So if I'm understanding closures I need another function to return an object with a view function (like my current object)? And then I pass the DOM element as an argument to m or to m.mount?

Comment: Wait, I missed the bottom of your code where you call mount. I think I see how it should work, I'll give it a try and see if it fixes my issues.

Comment: That last line depends on how your application is setup.  Usually you just use `m.mount` or `m.route` or something to that affect just once in your entire application.

Comment: @adaliabooks I changed the mount call so its more obvious, it doesn't really have anything to do with the closure thing.  Mount just expects any component.  If you are using routes or something you might not need `mount` I just had it setup to test it.

Comment: mount is fine, that's what I'm using at the moment.

Comment: What would I do instead of passing this to `createActionEditorList`? The UI elements the function creates contain references to `deleteAction` (and the function is used by another UI element) so that seemed to be the easiest way to reference it. Should it just be `EditModeElements`?

Comment: @adaliabooks I'm not sure what you're doing in that function but it might be easiest to pass in callbacks to write `onDeleteAction` and plain data to read `actions`.  I refactored my stub code into a component called `ActionEditorList`.

Comment: That makes sense, I think I can refactor that and make it work. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The only problem I can see is that I need to access some of the variables and functions of `EditModeElements` in other areas of the code and don't seem to be able to because it's a function now.

Comment: @adaliabooks You might want to refactor your app so that either the topmost component contains the commonly used state and passes it with callbacks into nested components or to use a state object across your app and use components more like views which mithril docs explain here -- https://mithril.js.org/components.html#avoid-fat-components

Comment: It's looking like that might be the best option.. I'd thrown in Mithril to make my UI easier to do halfway through and I'm not sure it was the best idea now. Thanks for the help, I'll have a good look and see what I can do to fix it properly.

Comment: In general, 

* Lambda all your event callbacks, instead of function(). Then `this` should  be captured from the view(). 
* Take advantage of closures. The first line of all my
   view = () => {
   const my = this;
   }
  on my code. And I always refer to my. within the callbacks. This will
  largely eliminate the ambiguity of what `this` is no matter where
  I use my in the view.